# Prometheus exporter to convert xml output to name-value pair

Tags: xml, websphere, prometheus, jmx-exporter, mbeanexporter

Websphere monitoring with little configuration provides URL to extract monitoring data in an XML format from PMI. Is there an exporter to convert XML data from PMI to name=value pair/JSON format?
I am trying to modify the logic in JMX collector to fit this. Looking for Any other better ideas?